# Parsing sqlite3 query responses in ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to read and parse an sqlite3 query in Ruby using the `sqlite3` gem. This db already exists on my machine.

I'm opening the db with

`db = SQLite3::Database.new "/path to/database.sqlite"`

The I'm executing my particular query with

`` db.execute( "SELECT * FROM `ZSFNOTE` WHERE `ZTRASHED` LIKE '0'" ) do |row| ``

Now, based on my (limited) experience, I was hoping that this could be parsed like a JSON response, where I could call something like `row["ZTITLE"]`. However, those headers aren't available in my response, I can only get at what I'm looking for by guessing an integer, like `row[19]`.

I know I'm not even scratching the surface of the `sqlite3` gem, but couldn't find the answer to this in the docs. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `*` but write out the columns you actually want.

Comment: That works, but is there no way to include the columns in the `*` query response?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [#execute2](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/1.3.11/SQLite3/Database#execute2-instance_method) to get the headers.

```
require 'sqlite3'
db = SQLite3::Database.new(':memory:')
db.execute 'CREATE TABLE "examples" ("header" varchar(20), "value" integer(8))'
db.execute 'INSERT INTO examples(header, value) VALUES("example", 1)'
db.execute2('select * from examples')
# => [["header", "value"], ["example", 1]]
```

You can map the headers to the columns like so:

```
headers, *rows = db.execute2('select * from examples')
rows.map! do |row|
    row.each_with_index.with_object({}) do |(col, i), o|
        o[headers[i]] = col
    end
end

rows.each do |row|
    p row['header']
end

# => "example"
```

Comment: Thanks—this is super helpful. But the behavior I was actually looking for was the [`results_as_hash`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/1.3.11/SQLite3/Database#results_as_hash-instance_method) variable, which I just discovered in the docs and returns items in a JSON-like array. Though you had no way of knowing exactly what I was looking for! Although, if I'm reading this correctly, it might also simplify what you are demonstrating here.